# PowerShell condition to execute command if character count is over some value

Tags: powershell, count, conditional-statements, rename

I'd like to execute this command only if the character count in filename is over 23.

```
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name.insert(23,'-old')}"
```

What would be the PowerShell condition command to do it?

The final command would loop through all files in folder and add suffix "-old" only to those with character count over 23.

Example:

```
input_filename1: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_X.txt
input_filename2: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XYYY.txt

output_filename1: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_X.txt
output_filename2: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_X-oldYYY.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you test it :

```
Get-ChildItem blabla | where {$_.name.length -gt 23} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name.insert(23,'-old')}
```

You perhaps test with BaseName.

```
Get-ChildItem blabla | where {$_.BaseName.length -gt 23} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name.insert(23,'-old')}
```

Comment: This one adds the "-old" regardless of the character count.

Comment: @Rayearth The condition here is correct. Where the name of the file is greater than 23 characters. You would need to update your question with an example of it not working otherwise.

Comment: @Rayearth can you give you full command line because it seams to work for me.

Comment: So BaseName is what you need.

Comment: It works with .BaseName but I'm wondering why its not working with just .Name. Anyway, thank You very much.

Comment: @Rayearth Name takes the extension, so in your case it takes the '.txt'.